# Messages Using Command prompt in Windows 7

Tags: command-line, windows-7, command, command-prompt

How to send `message` over network using `command prompt` in **windows 7** ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

"net send" is a command using a background service called "messenger".
This service has been removed from Windows 7.  ie **You cannot use 'net send' on Vista nor Win7 / Win8.**

Pity though , I loved using it.

There is alternatives, but that requires you to download and install software on each pc you want to use, this software runs as background services, and i would advise one to be very very very very careful of using these kind of software as they can potentially cause seriously damage one's system or impair the systems securities.

[winsent innocenti](http://www.winsentmessenger.com/innocenti/) / 
[winsent messenger](http://www.winsentmessenger.com/messenger/)

****This command is risky because of what is stated above***

Comment: This isn't entirely true. Win+R, type "services.msc", enable Messenger service. You have to enable the service. Or. Otherwise the new format is ">msg user_name message_here".

Comment: lol for "Neither I nor Stackoverflow or any affliates"... hahha

Answer (score 5):

Type "msg /?" in the command prompt to get various ways of sending meessages to a user.

Type "net send /?" in the command prompt to get another variation of sending messages across.

Comment: msg command is only sending msg to server, not working in window 7

Comment: @Arham ,I would love to see net send work in windows vista onwards. Could you explain how it works when the service itself has been removed from the operating system? Windows Messenger was replaced by Windows Live Messenger after XP , merged with Skype after microsoft bought it. rather look into alternative applications as messaging by default needs a server and client(s) relationship which is a million times more efficient, more reliable and best of all capable of being monitored via a server host.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **net send** command to send a message over a network.

example:

```
net send * How Are You
```

you can use the above statement to send a message to all members of your domain.But if you want to send a message to a single user named Mike, you can use

```
 net send mike hello!
```

this will send **hello!** to the user named Mike.

Answer (score -3):

Open Notepad and write this

```
@echo off
:A
Cls
echo MESSENGER
set /p n=User:
set /p m=Message:
net send %n% %m%
Pause
Goto A
```

and then save as "`Messenger.bat`" and close the Notepad
Step 1:

when you open that saved notepad file it will open as a file Messenger command prompt
with this details.

Messenger
**User:**

after "`User`" write the ip of the computer you want to contact and then press enter.